# UI Automation: How to change value of a horizontal scrollbar AutomationElement

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, user-interface, automation, scrollbar

I am trying to change the value of a horizontal scrollbar from -1 to -2.
I am able to get access to it.. but next i have to change its value..

`AutomationElement _sideBar = _ClickButtonElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "WindowsForms10.SCROLLBAR.app.0.378734a"));`

_clickButtonElement is the AutomationElement of the parent window of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Scrollbars usually support [RangeValuePattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.rangevaluepattern.aspx). Use something like:

```
RangeValuePattern range = scrollbar.GetCurrentPattern(RangeValuePattern.Pattern) as RangeValuePattern;
range.SetValue(50); // Set to half way point
```

Note that usually scrollbars are normalized to 0..100, regardless of internal values. So if a scrollbar internally uses values -5 to 5, then the scrollbar's half-way point of 0 will actually be exposed via RangeValuePattern as 50.

You might want to use the [Inspect tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) to ensure that you are getting the correct element, and that it also supports this pattern. You can also use Inspect to call RangeValue.SetValue() through its UI before you write any code.

Comment: Thanks for help. Still it gives an exception as "Unsupported Pattern." In debaugging mode, "LocalizedControlType" property in the "Current" property shows it as "pane". "Name" property is assigned as "Horizontal scroll bar." And the "Class" for that element as observed in spy++ is "WindowsForms10.SCROLLBAR.app.0.378734a" which i have used above. This is the information i could find out..

Comment: You might want to explore the tree to see if there's an actual scrollbar control someone nearby; perhaps as a child or as a sibling of the one you have. Sometimes controls have extra panes as parents or ancestors to manage layout. Curious, what app is this - is it a well-known app, or your own code or some in-house app?

Comment: That is the only srollbar type of element in the window. The app was developed by some people in company. No source code is available. It is a windows application. The element i am refering is the leaf node in the tree. No other similar element in the tree.It is the child of application window. I am sure i am accessing it correctly(by classNameProperty -mentioned above.). But no idea of changing it's value. Thanks for your interest to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
AutomationElement aeForm = AutomationElement.FromHandle(windowPtr);

AutomationElementCollection buttonCollection = aeForm.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.ScrollBar));          

AutomationElement aeButton = buttonCollection[1];

RangeValuePattern rcpattern = (RangeValuePattern)aeButton.GetCurrentPattern(RangeValuePattern.Pattern);
rcpattern.SetValue(50.00);
```