# Coded UI issue: How to scroll in a web page using Coded UI script

Tags: css, coded-ui-tests

I have two scroll bars(Horizontal and Vertical) in web page(css+html). This scroll bars are browser default controls.

My issue is: Coded UI is not able to identify vertical scroll bar and identifying horizontal scroll bar as single control, so not sure where to click for scroll.

Developers are using css property for scroll bar. So it automatically detects the overflow of data in defined container(horizontal as well as vertical).

Appreciate help on this issue, please let me know how to scroll horizontally and vertically in a web page.

Best Regards,
Sunil

Comment: Will the `UITestControl` method `EnsureClickable` help?

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI allows you to move the scroll wheel on your mouse by using [`Mouse.MoveScrollWheel()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitesting.mouse.movescrollwheel.aspx).  You can specify a number of wheel scrolls (which is actually just partial movements of the wheel), an optional modifier key to hold while the wheel is turned, and even a UITestControl to move the wheel over (useful if you have a text area within your page that has a scroll bar).

As far as horizontal scrolling, I wasn't able to find a method within Coded UI to do this, but  [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11010940/ui-automation-how-to-change-value-of-a-horizontal-scrollbar-automationelement) covers using `System.Windows.Automation` to complete the task.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a similar question where I wanted to scroll a page vertically by specific pixel. You can check the solution here. [Scroll web page in codedui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059419/in-codedui-how-to-scroll-a-page-vertically-by-required-pixel/24060644#24060644). The solution is not entirely CodedUI but by using the native control we can scroll the page both horizontally and vertically by required pixel.